# How to reload the child components based on some events from parent (RC4)

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

i have some child components listed as directives in a parent component, i wanted to reload all the child components based on some events triggered from one of the child component.

Please refer the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/x19FmBkf0mP1A6xvre8B?p=preview
Please refer the snapshot of my requirement
[image]
In plunker you can notice that the layout component has the applicationlist and ReportGroupList components in the directives.
my requirement is when the applicationlist component emits some event based on user interaction, the ReportGroupList component (sibling to the applicationlist component) to be reloaded. This ReportGroupList component is loaded based on the applicationList dropdown option selected. So every time the applicationlist dropdown option being changed the other components inside layout to be reloaded.

```
@Component({
  selector:'layout',
  inputs:['loggedInUser'],
    template: `
<Application-List ></Application-List>

    ReportGroupList:
    <ReportGroupList></ReportGroupList>
    `,
    directives:[ReportGroupList, ApplicationList, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

what is the way to do this?